# regex to extract two strings in sentence

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract both strings below to become ABC-DEF . What is a good regex to do this?

data-package-before-location="ABC" data-package-after-location="DEF"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review your question after referring to [StackOverflow - How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to show some evidence of the attempts you have made in relation to the question posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "data-package-before-location=\"ABC\" data-package-after-location=\"DEF\"";
            string pattern = @"(?'key'[\w-]+)=""(?'value'\w+)""";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            foreach (Match match in matches.Cast<Match>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I use pattern just non programmatically? I tested the string pattern in below but did not match https://regex101.com/

Comment: It work at link for me.  I replaces the two double quotes with a single double quote.  The input doesn't need the double quotes nor backslash.  The patter also does not need the ampersand and the double quotes at beginning and end.